# How to configure Maven to not use proxy server

Tags: maven

I am trying to configure Maven to not use a proxy server. This turns out to be a lot of work. Somewhere Maven has read some proxy information which it keeps on using.

I tried the following already.

1. in the terminal unset `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`
2. I did not have a `settings.xml`. I added one and added a proxy config to it with `active` is `false`
3. In settings.xml `active = true` and `nonProxyHosts = *`
4. I remove proxy settings from `/etc/environment`

I don't want to install a local proxy server just to get this working, is there another way to tell Maven not to use a proxy server.

Comment: A workaround is to use ssh tunnel as proxy server for example ssh -d $PORT user@server and then export MAVEN_OPTS="-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=$PORT"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step is to ask Maven to show you what configuration it sees/uses. Use the Help plugin for this: `mvn help:effective-pom` shows you the complete POM that Maven will use and `help:effective-settings` will do the same for the `settings.xml`.

Now you can see whether there are any proxy settings in those outputs, just to make sure the Maven universe is clean. My guess is that someone changes the global/default `settings.xml` from the `conf` folder of your Maven installation.

Afterwards, you need to check the proxy options which Java uses. Check your environment and the file `$HOME/.mavenrc`

Comment: [ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin' from the repositories [local (/home/ostraaten/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

Comment: That means Maven can't download the plugin. This is bad (hen-egg-problem) :-/ You can't simply download the plugin either, since it has a couple of dependencies. Can you try to install Maven again using the archives from maven.apache.org?

Comment: Reinstall did not fix this. Still plugin not found

Comment: Try `mvn -X` Maybe you can see in the output which files it reads.

Comment: Now would be a good time to run the `help` plugin so you have it available when it breaks again.